# How to set padding text when using keyframe text animation in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a text slide up/down animation.

I have the problem with padding when text animation.

Seem text when an animation does not show correct at center.

I want to all text should be shown at center.

You can see the code here:

```css
.flipword {
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* padding-top: 200px; */
    /* position: fixed; */
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 45%;
    display: block;
}

#flip {
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#flip>div>div {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
    animation: show 10s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
    background: #42c58a;
}

#flip div:first-child div {
    background: #4ec7f3;
}

#flip div:last-child div {
    background: #DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
    5% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    33% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    38% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    66% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    71% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    99.99% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flipword">
  <div id="flip">
    <div><div>Not Center</div></div>
    <div><div>Is Center</div></div>
    <div><div>Not Center</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css should be like this. take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/tamvo/m25b1vLa/

```
.flipword {
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* padding-top: 200px; */
    /* position: fixed; */
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 45%;
    display: block;
}

#flip {
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#flip>div>div {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {
    animation: show 10s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
    background: #42c58a;
}

#flip div:first-child div {
    background: #4ec7f3;
}

#flip div:last-child div {
    background: #DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
    5% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    33% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    38% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    66% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    71% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    99.99% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more information about your answer?

Comment: @vanloc: comment added to the fiddle, you can check it. If it is not clear, I'll use Vietnamese then :))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

```css
.flipword {
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* padding-top: 200px; */
    /* position: fixed; */
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 45%;
    display: block;
}

#flip {
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#flip>div>div {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    height: 57px;
    line-height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#flip div:first-child {

    animation: show 10s linear infinite;
}

#flip div div {
    background: #42c58a;
}

#flip div:first-child div {
    background: #4ec7f3;
}

#flip div:last-child div {
    background: #DC143C;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {
        margin-top: -194px;
    }
    5% {
        margin-top: -194px;
    }
    33% {
        margin-top: -194px;
    }
    38% {
        margin-top: -92px;
    }
    66% {
        margin-top: -92px;
    }
    71% {
        margin-top: -2px;
    }
    99.99% {
        margin-top: -2px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -194px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flipword">
  <div id="flip">
    <div><div>Not Center</div></div>
    <div><div>Is Center</div></div>
    <div><div>Not Center</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```